# Flagging answers as 'not an answer'...what happens if the answer is then improved?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-weight, not-an-answer

Apologies if this has already been asked, I couldn't find anything using the search.

If I was to flag an answer as 'not an answer' because (obviously) it did not answer the question, and the answer was then improved and became credible, what happens in the flag review process? Would my flag weight be decreased because it would appear I've marked a perfectly reasonable answer as 'not an answer'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mods know that this sort of thing happens, and they do tend to look at flags in context. There have been [proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105453/moderators-should-see-the-post-as-i-flagged-it-not-the-edited-version) to make them automatically see flagged posts as they were when flagged, but they haven't been implemented. There have been a handful of mistakes, but the only damage is a few flag weight points, and those aren't hard to regain.