# Show us the flagged revision for Spam/offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags, moderator-tools

Yesterday I got a puzzling flag; someone flagged a Not Constructive question as "Offensive". I went and closed it but dismissed the offensive flag with a "WTF". Upon reviewing the revision history, the post originally opened with an offensive remark; enough for me to immediately suspend the user.

Since Spam/Offensive posts are often edited very quickly to remove offending content, it'd be nice if the "offensive" revision was what's shown in the mod history; show us *exactly* what people flagged so we know why they flagged it.

Comment: Or, perhaps, some indication that a post was edited since the flag was submitted.

Comment: @AlEverett that at least would help, with a link to the first flagged revision

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105453/moderators-should-see-the-post-as-i-flagged-it-not-the-edited-version

Comment: @Clive related but the reasoning there doesn't quite apply to Spam/Offensive. If a Q flagged NC is no longer NC that's fine, but if a post WAS offensive/spam and has been whitewashed, it's still important to know

Comment: @Ben Agreed, I thought it was an interesting comparison though